# Aerospike - add new key/value pair in nested object

Tags: node.js, json, nested, aerospike

In Aerospike, how can I add a new key/value pair in nested object stored in bins of type map?

For ex,
I have a bins of type map against which I need to store below key/value pairs.

```
{
  "a" : "apple",
  "b" : "ball",
  "c" : { "d" : "dog", "e" : "elephant" }, 
  "f" : { "g" : { "h" : "horse" } },
  "i" : { "j" : "jackal", "k" : { "l" : "lion", "m" : "monkey" } }
}
```

Now, I want to update an existing nested object against key "k" to add one more key value pair like below.

```
"k" : { "l" : "lion", "m" : "monkey", "n" : "nest" }
```

Final result should be like below.

```
{
  "a" : "apple",
  "b" : "ball",
  "c" : { "d" : "dog", "e" : "elephant" }, 
  "f" : { "g" : { "h" : "horse" } },
  "i" : { "j" : "jackal", "k" : { "l" : "lion", "m" : "monkey", "n" : "nest" } }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
It's a NodeJS (10.6.0) application & I'm using NodeJS aerospike client (3.6.1) to interact with Aerospike (4.3.0.7).

Answer (score 8):

Updates on nested CDT maps and lists are possible now, using [Aerospike server version 4.6](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#4.6.0.2) or later and [Aerospike Node.js client version 3.12](https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/nodejs/notes.html#3.12.0) or later. That update introduced the [`withContext()` function](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/module-aerospike_maps-MapOperation.html#withContext) on list and map operations that lets you specify the context in which the list/map operation is to be executed. You can find more information in the documentation for the new [`CdtContext` class](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/nodejs/CdtContext.html).

Here is how you would perform the update given in your example:

```js
const Aerospike = require('aerospike')
const maps = Aerospike.maps

Aerospike.connect().then(async (client) => {
  const key = new Aerospike.Key('test', 'test', 'test')

  const map = {
    "a" : "apple",
    "b" : "ball",
    "c" : { "d" : "dog", "e" : "elephant" },
    "f" : { "g" : { "h" : "horse" } },
    "i" : { "j" : "jackal", "k" : { "l" : "lion", "m" : "monkey" } }
  }
  console.log('BEFORE:', map)
  await client.put(key, map)

  await client.operate(key, [
    maps.put('i', 'n', 'nest')
        .withContext((ctx) => ctx.addMapKey('k'))
  ])
  const record = await client.get(key)
  console.log('AFTER:', record.bins)

  client.close()
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
  if (error.client) error.client.close()
})
```

Here is what you would get, when you run the example:

```
$ node nested-map-update-example.js
BEFORE: {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'ball',
  c: { d: 'dog', e: 'elephant' },
  f: { g: { h: 'horse' } },
  i: { j: 'jackal', k: { l: 'lion', m: 'monkey' } }
}
AFTER: {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'ball',
  c: { d: 'dog', e: 'elephant' },
  f: { g: { h: 'horse' } },
  i: { j: 'jackal', k: { l: 'lion', m: 'monkey', n: 'nest' } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to update the full value for the key "i".

Comment: In that case I need to first do a get & then update. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: You can flatten out your nested map - use keys such as "i-j", "i-k", or do a read-modify-write with write policy GEN_EQUAL so you make sure that you did not get a write from another client between your read and write.

Comment: This is no longer true, as of Aerospike server version 4.6. Updates on nested lists/maps can now be performed without fetching/updating the full list/map bin value first. See my answer for more details.